# Export PDF without marks and bleeds

Tags: adobe-photoshop, bleed

I'm required to export a PDF with size 8.5 x 11 (inches) PDF with no bleeds or markings.

I've designed my page and now I'm trying to export it as PDF. I've tried `File > Save As > Photoshop PDF` and seen on many tutorials and online resources that there should be a `Marks And Bleeds` menu section in which I can crop them but I don't see any.

[image]

If I export the file this way and then try to print it I see a white margin around the image.

[image]

How am I supposed to proceed in order to be sure the file is properly exported for the company who is going to print it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **printer** (HP OfficeJet) requires the margin. That does not mean the margin is part of the PDF itself.

Borderless printing, or printing to the edge of a sheet, is a function of the **printer** not part of the software, or any PDF.

View the PDF in **Acrobat** to ensure its got the proper marks and size.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the photoshop file, did you create it at 8.5 x 11 size?

In Photoshop, the marks and bleeds options are available when you go to the print setting. By default, they are typically off/unchecked. But you're not handling the printing anyway - someone else is and they are instructing you to just give them an 8.5 x 11 size file.  So in your case here, there is nothing you need to do further as long as the document size is created at 8.5 x 11. When you save the PDF, the PDF page size will be 8.5 x 11.

Now if you didn't create the file at 8.5 x 11 size (or you created it with bleeds at a larger size), simply shrink the canvas size to 8.5 x 11 to exclude the bleeds and then export to PDF. The person doing the printing will handle the rest.